# GtkVScale and GtkHScale keyboard arrow and up/down keys confusion

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I'm a bit confused about why GtkHScale responds to the up/down keys and GtkVScale resoonds to the Left/Right keys.  Even more confusing is that they seem to move the wrong direction, ie: I would expect Up to move GtkHScale right, and Right to move GtkVScale Up.  Is there a UI reason for this behavior?  Is it possible to block up/down from GtkHScale and left/right from GtkVScale using something like key-press-event and key-release-event?

Comment: Re the up vs down, think of up and left as previous and down and right as next and you'll see why it is as it is (exceping the fact lr respond to vscale and ud respond to hscale in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can return TRUE for the questionable keys in key_press_event and key_release_event and that blocks the behavior.  Now it may be that doing so will confuse someone used to the other keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [direction inversion bug in GTK+ 3](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=407242). It has since then be fixed in what will become GTK+ 4, but the change will probably not be backported to keep behavior consistent across minor versions of GTK+ 3.